# Where to inject class. In using class or in caller class

Tags: java, spring, oop, spring-boot

I have a PropertiesUtil class which is used as container for some configuration properties of my `application.properties` file.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application.property")
public abstract class PropertiesUtil {

    private String networkLocation;
    private String topLevelPrefix;
```

I have to use this class on different places in my application.

**My question is** should I inject this class on every place I need it or should I inject this class on a caller class and give it as parameter to a method.

For example injection in using class:

```
@Component
public class FileExport {

    private final PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil;

    @Autowired
    public FileExport(PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil) {
        this.propertiesUtil = propertiesUtil;
    }

    public List<File> getListOfFileAndRules(String topLevelName){
      // logic and use of propertiesUtil
    }
```

or for example injection in caller class:

```
@Component
public class AnyClass{

    private final PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil;
    private final FileExport fileExport;

    @Autowired
    public AnyClass(PropertiesUtil propertiesUtil, FileExport fileExport) {
        this.propertiesUtil = propertiesUtil;
        this.fileExport= fileExport;
    }

    public void anyMethod(){
        List<file> fiels = fileExport.getListOfFileAndRules(anyString, propertiesUtil);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the architecture of your application and the kind of configuration parameters. I often distinguish between runtime and startup configuration - while the first is intended to change or just *may* change during runtime, the latter is intended to be set on startup (or *once*) and not changed during runtime of the application.

In your case I assume the params to be startup-configuration, thus I'd suggest to inject it to all the classes where it is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would inject it into the using class, because your caller class don't need this information. If you have different 'using' classes I would think about creating of one abstract class for extends & put the injection inside this one.

If you put your properties into the caller class you put it into your API and that isn't good. Your classes should be as simple as possible in usage, also for testing.